# Clarification on a console.log of a Javascript object

Tags: node.js, formidable

This seems to be basic but I am missing something. I am using the node.js formidable module and am console logging the error as in:

```
uploadProc.on('error', function(err) {
   console.log("Form upload error...");
   console.log(typeof err);
   console.log(err);
   console.log(err[0]);
   console.log(err['Error']);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(err);
});
```

The output is:

```
object
[Error: Request aborted]
undefined
undefined
{}
```

As I see, it is neither an array nor a regular object with the property Error. If I want to stringify it, whatever type it is, how do I do that?  May be it is string to begin with. But if that was the case, typeof would have returned "string." I check this at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). Seems to fall in the "any other object" category. Can someone explain what type of an object that is console logged as [Error: Request aborted] is?

Comment: It's an [Error object](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_error). In what way do you want to stringify it (what do you expect the output to be)?

Comment: @robertklep you should post your comment as the answer.

Comment: @yeiniel it's not an answer (yet) :-) it's not clear to me what the "stringify" step should yield (name, stack trace, etc).

Comment: @robertklep the docs doesn't say nothing about. The Op need to use the `message` and `stack` properties as described in docs

Comment: @roberklep I had looked at the error object [here]( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) on Mozilla dev site.  This object or its prototype does not have any of the message, name, stack or any such properties.  I am missing something basic.

Comment: @Sam you should look at the Node documentation instead. See my answer, which links to it.

Comment: @robertklep Got it!  the "message" property. I wrongly used the prototype.message property to get the string this time.   If you post it as an answer, will be happy to accept it. Sub question: Does console.log treat the error object differently and displays the message property of the error object with the "Error: " prefix? Where is that "Error: " string coming from in console.log? May be I need to look closely at the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [Error object](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_error):

```
> new Error('hello world') instanceof Error
true
```

It has a `.toString()` method that you can use to stringify it:

```
> console.log(new Error('hello world').toString())
Error: hello world
```

Or, if you want to output the stack trace:

```
> console.log(new Error('hello world').stack)
Error: hello world
    at repl:1:13
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:262:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:431:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:550:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:827:14)
```

Comment: Perfect explanation! Got a lot more info then I asked. Very educational!